# Markdown cell latex producing unwanted vertical bar

Tags: jupyter-notebook

Vertical bars are being shown after latex sections when markdown cells are rendered. Is there any way to remove these?

For example, the following code inside a markdown cell:

```
$\left[ \begin{array}{cccc}
x_{11} & x_{12} & \ldots & x_{1D} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} & \ldots & x_{2D} \\
x_{31} & x_{32} & \ldots & x_{3D} \\ \end{array} \right]$
```

renders as

[image: Matrix]

and

```
$\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{D\times K}$
```

renders as

[image: Text]

#### Software Versions

Mac OS 10.10.5

chrome 48.0.2564.48 (Official Build) beta (64-bit)

`ipython notebook --version` 4.0.6

Comment: this issue is probably not related to jupyter. I cannot reproduce this here.

Comment: [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) please :)

Comment: Is a MWE applicable to an ipython notebook? To reproduce, type the code I've provided into a markdown cell and compile. The ipython notebook will compile the LaTeX under the hood. 

However @cel mentions that they cant reproduce. I presume that I have a local issue. Any tips on debugging appreciated.

Comment: Do you see the same issue in safari?

Comment: No I don't. How weird!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the issue about this on jupyter repository, closed and merged in the beginning of February: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1059

Answer (score 3):

I find this problem occurs in Chrome 48.0.2564.97, but not Firefox, in both Windows 10 and Ubuntu.